# What does Some(string.!!) mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have

```
val str = s"""/bin/bash -c 'some command'"""
job = Some(str.!!)
```

It is meant to execute the bash command I assume.

Can someone explain this syntax? 
Googling for '.!!' doesn't help much neither does 'dot exclamation exclamation' so I hope someone can explain this one and/or point me to the doc.

The job doesn't run and I'm trying to debug the code, but when i put this in a

```
try {
   command = Some(str.!!)
} 
catch { 
case e:Exception => 
  println(e.toString)
}
```

e is actually not an Exception for some reason...
Trying to figure what this really does and how to find what is happening.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.package

Comment: thanks... i read also :
```import scala.sys.process._

// This uses ! to get the exit code
def fileExists(name: String) = Seq("test", "-f", name).! == 0

// This uses !! to get the whole result as a string
val dirContents = "ls".!!```

so .!! should get a string result.

Comment: if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.
Do you know what the Exception thrown should be in this case?

Comment: Why not run it in a REPL and find out what exception it throws?

Comment: Side note: In general you should use [`NonFatal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.NonFatal$) when you want to catch all exceptions.

Comment: what's REPL? not sure what you mean.

Comment: [Read-eval-print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), sometimes called an interactive interpreter or shell. Open a terminal and run `scala` with no arguments. You type scala expressions into it, and it evaluates them.

Comment: You can look up symbolic operators like `!!` in the Scaladoc index, here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/#index.index-_

Comment: thanks @Seth Tisue, this is very helpful... I thought Scala was obscure, now I have proof!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an [implicit conversion](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package@stringToProcess%28command:String%29:scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) from `String` to `ProcessBuilder`. When you import `scala.sys.process._` then scala will automatically perform the conversion when needed, thus making the method `!!` available on String instances. You can find the methods of ProcessBuilder here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder

The documentation for `!!` says that "If the exit code is non-zero, an exception is thrown." It appears that bash in this case does return `0`, so the command was for some reason successful.